# Elliptic point of surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, elliptic-curves, curvature

Why does a point $p$ in a surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the Gaussian curvature is positive is called elliptic point?

Comment: Consider the folowing three surfaces: the sphere (equilateral ellipsoid), the hyperbolic paraboloid and the paraboloid. In the first the principal curvatures have same signals, in the second one the principal curvatures have opposite signals, and in the last one at leat one of them is null.

Comment: When we say that a point is elliptic, then in such point both principal curvatures are positive (or negative, depends on the normal vetor orientation). Locally it is a ellipsoid.

Comment: If ${\rm II}$ stands for the second fundamental form of $S$, then the Dupin indicatrix $\{v\in T_pS \mid {\rm II}_p(v,v)=1\}\subseteq T_pS$ is an ellipse, provided $K(p)>0$.

Comment: do you know the relations of the coeficientes of second fundamental form and the curvatures? I'm also trying to find such relations.